# Extracting part of a string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to extract the classname from a list of UE4 blueprint paths that look like this:

```
"Blueprint'/Game/Aberration/CoreBlueprints/Weapons/PrimalItemAmmo_Zipline.PrimalItemAmmo_Zipline'"
```

The end result needs to be something like this:

```
PrimalItemAmmo_Zipline_C
```

I guess the easiest way would be to extract everything between the "." and the apostrophe at the end, before appending the _C. I've tried a few different solutions I've found online, mostly modified from formulas for getting filenames from filepaths, but I can't get any of them to work properly.
What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string in A1, try

```
=substitute(regexextract(A1, "[^.]*$"), char(39)&char(34), "_C")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: That pulled the word Blueprint from the start of the path.

Comment: Wait, apparently I've just been having a major brain collapse and have been testing all my formulas on G1 when the path is in G2... I'm an idiot and this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\.(.*)'")&"_C"
```

[image: 0]

---

for array do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\.(.*)'")&"_C"))
```

[image: 0]